# How to add column from other table after converting the value in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one table having a column darm_review. i want to add this column to another table with convert value using sql query.
0 to No
1 to Yes
NULL to Undefined

eg:-
table1

```
darm_review
0
1
NULL
```

now i want to add this column in table2 like this
table2

```
darm_review
No
Yes
Undefined
```

Please help me how to do this.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store values from other tables. (Redundancy, data inconsistency.) Either create a view. Or use triggers.

Comment: Does the other table exist or do you want to create it?

Comment: yes both the table already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `case when` expression

```
select darm_review, 
      case when darm_review='No' then 0 
           when darm_review=1 then 'Yes' 
           when darm_review='Undefined' then null end as conditionalValue
from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is will insert all the records of table1 into table 2 and during insertion it will also replace data of darm_review  as per requirement.

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE 2 
      SELECT  c1,c2,
    CASE
        WHEN darm_review = 0 THEN "No"
        WHEN darm_review = 1 THEN "YES"
        WHEN darm_review IS NULL THEN "Undefined"
    END AS T
    FROM TABLE1
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think you should explain why you suggest this solution. It tells nothing as it is.

Comment: Sure ! This is will insert all the records of table1 into table 2 and during insertion it will also replace data of darm_review  as per requirement.